# sum of digits of a number

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to make a program with JavaScript which adds the digits of a number until the number of digits in the result is 1.

Example:

```
57 = 5 + 7 = 12 = 1 + 2 = 3.
```

I have made a program which does half of the job.
Here is it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Try</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form><input type="text" onkeyup="sumofDigits(this.value)"></input>
    </form>
    <h1></h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sumofDigits(number) {
            var num = number.toString();
            var sum = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
                sum += parseInt(num.charAt(i), 10);
            }

            document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = sum;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _digits of a number and then the digits of the result until the number of digits of result is 1_ ? Could not read it..

Comment: Check the question now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need of string functions here.
You can simply arrive the result with help of mod(**%** operation.

```
function sumDigits(number) {
      document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = ((number-1)%9+1);
}
```

Comment: Beware of corner cases: The solution for 999 should be 999 → 27 → 9. The solution for 0 should be 0, however.

Comment: you can use **((number-1)%9+1)** istead to avoid such cases. Check the corrected one now.

Answer (score 2):

This does it.

```
function sumDigits(number) {
    var num = number.toString();

    while (num.length != 1) {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            sum += parseInt(num.charAt(i), 10);
        }
        num = sum.toString();
        document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumDigits(number) {
    var str = number.toString();
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(str.charAt(i), 10);
    }

    if (sum > 9)  
        sumDigits(sum);
      else           
        document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = sum;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sumDigits(number) {
        while( number > 9){
            var num = number.toString();
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
                sum += parseInt(num.charAt(i), 10);
            }
            number = sum;
        }
        document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = sum;
    }
</script>
```